# centering the axis/pivot of a polydata model in python-vtk/three.js

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, three.js, vtk

I am creating a 3D model from a series of dicom images. The workflow that I am using is as follows:

- Read the dicom series with `vtkDICOMImageReader`.
- Get the Threshold image from the volume with `vtkImageThreshold`.
- Generate a 3D model using the Discrete Marching Cubes algorithm.
- Write the output as PLY file using the `vtkPLYWriter`.

When I look at the ply file using meshlab, it looks likes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDjWQ.png) (from the back).

The problem that Im facing is that, the axis/pivot are not at the center of the model. So is there a way to fix this?? I know that I need to use the `vtkTransformfilter` to do it (I think, I might be wrong), but I just dont know how.

I did look at the vtk examples given at their site, but it did not give enough information on what I wanted. I also searched the other questions in the SO, but most of them are using vtkActors and renderers, and didnt solve the problem that I have.

The dicom set that I am using is from [here](https://mri.radiology.uiowa.edu/VHDicom/VHMCT1mm/VHMCT1mm_Head.tar.gz).

I would also like to know if its possible to do this in Three.js, like load the model and then center it?

Thank you

Comment: Ok after searching online the entire night, I was able to find a small work around to the problem in three.js. Using `THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );` after loading the model, it will center it to the world and will also reset the pivot. But I would still like to know how to reset this in vtk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ok to move the model, then you can define the center of the model, and transform it to the global origin, then save the transformed model as a PLY file.

First, you want to define the center of the model. A quick and dirty way could be to get the center of mass:

```
centerFilter = vtk.vtkCenterOfMass()
centerFilter.SetInputData(polydata)
centerFilter.SetUseScalarsAsWeights(False)
centerFilter.Update()
center = centerFilter.GetCenter()
```

Then you want to transform your model:

```
transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
transform.Translate(-center[0], -center[1], -center[2])
transformFilter = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
transformFilter.SetInputData(polydata)
transformFilter.SetTransform(transform)
transformFilter.Update()
centeredPolydata = transformFilter.GetOutput()
```

Then write the output PLY file with centeredPolydata.

Note: this will make it more difficult to relate the centered model to the image data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will check it out, thank you.

Comment: That did work, thank you. and just leaving a comment here : If anyone wants to center the object using Three.js, they can simple use this `THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );` and it will center it to the browser screen.

Comment: yes centering a model is fairly easy, sketchup has a plugin, you can write code form the vertex data, meshlab surely has one, it's just a case of a solution that goes well to your workflow if you are doing alot of models, otherwise just se any program that does it.

Answer (score -1):

I can use vtkCenterOfMass with vtkImageReslice or vtkImageImport?